# Initiate Python Script on AWS from Wordpress

Tags: php, python, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have the following use case in which I need to run a Python script on a AWS hosted VM with information from a Wordpress site:

1) User enters a number of parameters in a form:

```
x = 3
y = 5
```

2) parameters are stored in the WP backend along with other user information from the WP backend database:

```
user = "John Doe"
```

3) as soon as all data is inputed, data is sent to Python server, which runs a very complex script (cannot be replicated in PHP)

```
def foo(x,y, user):
    bar = x + y
    print(user, " receives ", bar," as an answer.")
```

4) result of the script (bar) is then returned to WP and stored for further use

Data security is also a big issue in this case, so secured connections are a must.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight-forward enough to do - you need to develop a REST API endpoint in Python, running on your AWS instance and must be accessible from your wordpress site (with whatever security you need in place).

Checkout Flask / Flask-restful for the back-end piece and then you'll need to update your wordpress site to make the API call to execute the function and return the result.

Don't know a lot about wordpress, but I would be surprised if it was not a straightforward task to make an API call from it to any arbitrary endpoint with just a bit of custom code.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will a try a simple API first, however, I am on EC2 and I have heard it is having issues handling API calls in higher numbers.

Comment: WordPress is REST ready for quite some time now (4.4 iirc). You can easily create endpoints, and fetch any kind of data using `wp_remote_get()`.